# LINQ Union not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, union

I have written a following code like below:

```
  ViewBag.result = allStoreItems.Union(Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
            .Select(offset => new StoreAnalyticOrders { OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(30)).AddDays(offset), AmountPaid = 0 }))
                .SelectMany(x => x.StoreItemTransactions)
                .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.Date)
                .Select(cl => new StoreAnalyticOrders {
                    OrderDate = cl.Key,
                    AmountPaid = cl.Sum(c => c.TransactionPrice)
                })
               .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
              .ToList();
```

Basically what this code does is groups my avalilable dates from DB table and sums the values for the grouped days.

Please note the following part of the code:

```
.Union(Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
.Select(offset => new StoreItemTransactions { TransactionDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(30)).AddDays(offset), TransactionPrice = 0 }))
```

I'm trying to add those missing dates that don't exist in my DB. So for example if I' have dates like these:

```
  Date           Amount
21 Feb. 2017   (some amount here)
19 Feb. 2017
13 Feb. 2017
```

Now the output would be the missing days + the ones that already exist from today's date (which is 21 Feb. 2017);

Output should be:

```
Date             Amount
21 Feb. 2017    (some amounts here)
20 Feb. 2017
19 Feb. 2017
18 Feb. 2017
17 Feb. 2017
16 Feb. 2017
15 Feb. 2017
14 Feb. 2017
13 Feb. 2017
12 Feb. 2017
11 Feb. 2017
10 Feb. 2017
... all the way back to 21 Feb. -30 days
```

Dates which aren't present in the list are assigned value of 0 as you can see...

Other than that, allStoreItems is a list typed of StoreItems and as you can see I'm creating a new type ( a custom class that I made just to display these 2 properties on the View;

The error that I'm getting here is:

```
List<StoreItems> does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload Queryable.Union<StoreAnalyticOrders>(IQueryable<StoreAnalyticOrders>) requires a receiver of Type IQueryable<StoreAnalyticOrders>
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this ?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets here and there. It's particularly unhelpful that the piece you've supposedly highlighted from the first listing has changed (StoreAnalyticOrders vs StoreItemTransactions, OrderDate vs TransactionDate etc).

Comment: (I'd also *strongly* advise against using `DateTime.Now` in server-side code unless you *really* want to depend on your server's default time zone.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Should I use DateTimeUTC.Now? P.S. Order date and TransactionDate are both same type if this is what you are asking me for ? =)

Comment: You should usually use `DateTime.UtcNow`, yes. But my point is that you say "Please note the following part of the code" - but that *isn't* part of the code you've shown. But basically, we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with

```
      allStoreItems.Union(...)
```

then what follows **needs** to be the same type as allStoreItems and because it isn't, you get your error. Hence you need to move your union to later on. The simplest way to think about this is build two lists and then combine them.

Suppose you have your list

```
var list1  = allStoreItems
            .SelectMany(x => x.StoreItemTransactions)
            .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.Date)
            .Select(cl => new StoreAnalyticOrders {
                OrderDate = cl.Key,
                AmountPaid = cl.Sum(c => c.TransactionPrice)
            })
           .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
          .ToList();
```

Assuming that the above works and gives you a `List<StoreAnalyticOrders>` then you can get your second list by

```
 var list2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
        .Select(offset => new StoreAnalyticOrders { OrderDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-(30)).AddDays(offset), AmountPaid = 0 }).ToList();
```

You can then combine these lists using Union. However you need to create a method to indicate that you only want to compare the OrderDate and ignore the AmountPaid

That could be something like

```
public class StoreAnalyticOrdersComparer : IEqualityComparer<StoreAnalyticOrders>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<StoreAnalyticOrders>.Equals(StoreAnalyticOrders s1, StoreAnalyticOrders s2)
    {
        return s1.OrderDate == s2.OrderDate;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<StoreAnalyticOrders>.GetHashCode(StoreAnalyticOrders obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return 0;

        return obj.OrderDate.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This can be used like

```
ViewBag.result =  list1.Union(list2, new StoreAnalyticOrdersComparer())
                       .OrderBy(a=>a.OrderDate).ToList();
```